# UIView setting opacity issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, quartz-2d

I want to set different opacity for different pixels in UIView.

So, I need to find implementations for method `[self setProperOpacity:myView forX:x forY:y];` in code (so that function should set alfa value for proper pixels):

```
for (int x = 0; x < 320; x++)
{
     for (int y = 0; y < 460; y++)
     {
         [self setProperOpacity:myView forX:x forY:y];
     }
}
```

I will grateful for any approach of implementation `[self setProperOpacity:myView forX:x forY:y];`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Some kind of masking? Masking an image below the view?

Comment: yes, if you can provide such kind of code, that would be great

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your view is initially filled with black, and you want to clear some of the pixels to transparent. To do that you need to use the core graphics methods. Depending on where you want the code and how you want to do it the below code could be used either in `drawRect` of the view or to create a masking image (you need to get the context as appropriate):

```
CGContextRef ctx = ...;

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeNormal); 
CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460));

// CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeClear); // if you want to clear
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0].CGColor);

for (int x = 0; x < 320; x++)
{
  for (int y = 0; y < 460; y++)
  {
     CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake(x, y, 1, 1));
  }
}
```

The answer is based around the idea that you have a partially transparent view over the top of some other image (in another view behind) that you're trying to mask out. If you just have the image and you don't want multiple views then you could (in `drawRect`) draw the image to the context and then loop over the pixels that **should not** be transparent and paint them in another color using the code above.

Comment: but in this case I  think the image will be marked with grey spots, but I need to alfa to original pixels of the image